# Spring JPA Lazy loading @OneToOne entities doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I'm having trouble making `OrderEntity` object load `BillingAddress` lazily. I've seen questions revolving around this asked a lot and followed instructions, including adding optional = false but `BillingAddress` still gets loaded whenever I `findById` an `OrderEntity`.

These are my entities (reduced for the sake of this question):

**OrderEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders", schema = "glamitoms")
public class OrderEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private BillingAddressEntity billingAddress;

}
```

**BillingAddressEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "billing_address", schema = "glamitoms")
public class BillingAddressEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private OrderEntity order;
}
```

**TestController**

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    private OrdersDAO ordersDAO;

    @Autowired
    public TestController(OrdersDAO ordersDAO) {
        this.ordersDAO = ordersDAO;
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public void test() {
        OrderEntity orderEntity = ordersDAO.findById(1).get();
    }
}
```

**OrdersDAO**

```
@Repository
public interface OrdersDAO extends JpaRepository<OrderEntity, Integer> {
}
```

The table `billing_address` has a FK referencing orders. I've read contradicting answers saying adding `optional = false` should load entities lazily, but for me, that doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something in any of these entities?

Comment: You can use Bytecode Enhancement. See the detail answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60930929/4207306

Comment: Not sure about `Lazy Loading` but since you are doing `@MapsId`, hibernate is trying to fetch order. I was in similar situation, and in my case it was a kind of loop created. I Annotated OrderEnity order by @JsonIgnore (a tactical fix).

Comment: @Morgan What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: @SternK My hibernate version is 5.4.18

Comment: @YoManTaMero I don't understand. Isn't JsonIgnore a Jackson annotation? What does that have to do with hibernate?

Comment: @Morgan Do you really need bidirectional @OneToOne? If so, you should use bytecode enhancement. See [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one-bidirectional-lazy).

Comment: @SternK It'd be okay to just have the `BillingAddressEntity` in `OrderEntity`. But would that allow updating?

Comment: @Morgan Yes, sure. The approach described [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) perfectly works in hibernate 5.4. You should only use appropriate `CascadeType`.

Comment: @SternK bytecode enhancement worked, but only sometimes. I don't know if it's something to do with Intellij, but if I touch the `OrderEntity` class in any way without running `mvn clean install` first lazy loading doesn't work. I have found this, maybe related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-159903

Comment: @Morgan how are you verifying lazy loading isn't working?

Comment: @crizzis Debugger and Hibernate query logs.

Comment: @Morgan `JsonIgnore` indeed is Jackson annotation, but, for me entities were iteratively fetching record causing stack overflow.  Adding this annotation helped me suppress that iterative call.  If you look your sql logs, you probably will notice that SQL is just called once, but entity loads the relation iteratively.  This is not a proper solution but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Vlad Mihalceas article [The best way to map a @OneToOne relationship with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

As described there, one of the solutions would be to drop the relation on the parentside...

```
@Transient
private BillingAddressEntity billingAddress;
```

and load the `BillingAddressEntity` manually using the shared id.

```
if (order.billingAddress == null) 
{
   order.billingAddress = entityManager.find(BillingAddressEntity.class, order.id);
}
```

Another approach would be to drop the shared key, use a foreign key field instead and mark the relation as `@ManyToOne`. This will sacrifice the OneToOne constraint check though.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "billing_address_id")
private BillingAddressEntity billingAddress;
```

Then there's also the byte code enhancement which would allow you to make this a `@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)`relation. I can't help you with that though, as I've never done that myself.